# installing sas 9.3 on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: sas

I have installed sas 9.3 64bit on my ubunut 12.04(under the directory /usr/local/SASHome).  the installation was completed successfully. But when I try to launch sas under /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.3 ,I cannot find the file named sas.

using command ls, I can find 4 directory under the path: installs,misc,sasexe,utilities.
there are many .so files in the directory sasexe.

can amyone help me to solve this problem?  Forgive me if I'm not explaining this properly because I'm not familiar with linux sas.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a sas.sh script for launching SAS in that location.  I haven't installed 9.3 on Linux, so it might have changed since I last worked with it.

The sasexe directory is the location for the compiled shared objects (.so) files.  These are analogous to .dll in Windows.  You do not call them directly.